# Text flow around image - float & media &?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, notepad++

**I want text to flow around an image.** On *stackoverflow*, I found two differemt answers, both of which worked perfectly in the fiddly (?):

- **BLOCK -** with "clear:both" - works as expected but there's no padding between the text and the image - ugly, IMO
- **MEDIA -** nicely padded but it doesn't flow

When I executed the snippet here at *stackoverflow*, both examples looked different than in the real world (both Firefox & Chrome). The snippet is located at WoodLoon.com/t3.html ([link](http://woodfool.com/t3.html))

**Is there a better way that combines the virtues of both?**

```html
  <div class="row; ">
    <img style="height: 120px; float:left" src="http://WoodFool.com/Pictures/Ski.jpg">
    <p>IMAGE FLOAT LEFT = Experience 1 = text floats - Donec id elit non mi portnon mi a gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- Donec id elit non mi portnon miporta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- </p>
    <p>Experience continues = text floats - Donec id elit non mi portnon mi a gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- Donec id elit non mi portnon miporta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- </p>    
    <p style="clear:both"><strong>P has style="clear:both" -</strong> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="row; ">
   <div class="media; media-left">
    <span></span>
     <img style="height: 120px; float:left" src="http://WoodFool.com/Pictures/Ski.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
     <p class="media-heading">MEDIA BODY (MEDIA-LEFT ABOVE) Experience 2 = text floats -  Donec id elit non mi portnon mi a gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- Donec id elit non mi portnon miporta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- </p>
     <p>Experience continues = text floats - Donec id elit non mi portnon mi a gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- Donec id elit non mi portnon miporta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- </p>      
     <p style="clear:both"><strong>P has style="clear:both" -</strong> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>     
    </div>
   </div>
```

First time using your fiddly (?). Different results than in Firefox and Chrome - [here's a link](http://woodfool.com/t3.html) (I hope that's not breaking some rule - this is my 2nd post...)

Also, I use Notepad++ - I am impressed. When I run from my hard disk, it renders immediately on Firefox, but Chrome takes 23 seconds. I can actually save the file in N++, transfer the new HTML file in Filezilla, and then hit F5 in Chrome in under 23 seconds. Obviously it's unimportant, but it is irritating.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first row with the below markup.

```
<div class="row; "><!-- image 1 -->
            <div class="media; media-left"><img style="height: 120px; float:left" src="http://WoodFool.com/Pictures/Ski.jpg"></div>
            <div class="media-body"><p><strong>IMAGE FLOAT LEFT = Experience 1 = </strong>text floats - Donec id elit non mi portnon mi a gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- Donec id elit non mi portnon miporta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- </p>
            <p>Experience continues = text floats - Donec id elit non mi portnon mi a gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- Donec id elit non mi portnon miporta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui- </p>               
            <p style="clear:both"><strong>P has style="clear:both" -</strong> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you - I had div media-body within div media-left - making it div media-left and then div media-body makes the padding (?) good.

Comment: But it does not cause the text to wrap around the image.